# Oracle - Get first row after a row

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I would like to extract all the row with "A" status, and the first row for each account after the "A" status.
For example:

```
id   account   status
 1      X         A
 2      Y         C
 3      Y         A
 4      X         B
 5      X         C
 6      Y         C
 7      X         A
 8      X         C
 9      X         C
 ...
```

The expected output is

```
 1      X         A
 3      Y         A
 4      X         B
 6      Y         C
 7      X         A
 8      X         C
 ...
```

How could I do?

Comment: This question is not clear.  Please edit it.  Is the table you show, the expected output?  If so, please show the input table. Is "A -> Yes" the actual complete string in the table?  What have you tried?  What is "first row"?  That implies some sorting method.

Comment: "After" = with higher ID value

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `lag` function to "look back" at the previous row. Unfortunately you can't use window functions in the `where` clause, so you'll have to use a subquery:

```
SELECT id, account, status
FROM   (SELECT id, account, status,
               LAG(status) OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY id ASC) AS prev_status
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  'A' IN (status, prev_status)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12.1 or higher, MATCH_RECOGNIZE can do quick work of such assignments. The WITH clause is there just to provide test data (remove it before trying the solution).

```
with
  test_data(id, account, status) as (
    select 1, 'X', 'A' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Y', 'C' from dual union all
    select 3, 'Y', 'A' from dual union all
    select 4, 'X', 'B' from dual union all
    select 5, 'X', 'C' from dual union all
    select 6, 'Y', 'C' from dual union all
    select 7, 'X', 'A' from dual union all
    select 8, 'X', 'C' from dual union all
    select 9, 'X', 'C' from dual
  )
select id, account, status
from   test_data
match_recognize(
  partition by account
  order by     id
  all rows per match
  pattern      ( A X? )
  define       A as status = 'A',
               X as status is null or status != 'A'
)
order by id  -- if needed
 24  ;

    ID ACCOUNT STATUS
---------- ------- -------
     1 X       A
     3 Y       A
     4 X       B
     6 Y       C
     7 X       A
     8 X       C

6 rows selected.
```